# cURL + PHP to getting a class name, possible?

Tags: php, curl

Is it possible to get a certain class name through cURL?

For instance, I just want to get the 123 in this `<div class="123 photo"></div>`.

Is that possible?

Thanks for your responses!

Edit:

If this is whats seen on a website

```
<div class="444 photo">...</div>
<div class="123 photo">...</div>
<div class="141 photo">...</div>

etc...
```

I'm trying to get all the numbers of this class, and putting in an some array.

Comment: `cURL` simply retrieves content via different protocols. It does not search or manipulate that  content. We need more information on what you're trying to do, and how you're currently attempting to accomplish it.

Comment: cURL does not have text processing capabilities of its own. I assume you're asking if you can use PHP to do this extraction, and the answer is yes, you can use regular expressions.

Comment: @Morgon, what do you mean? I'm just trying to get the class name 123 from cURL of another website which I would need to init() or something, I'm still new.. thanks

Comment: @andrewliu: you can use cURL to fetch the remote page, there are a lot of examples and tutorials on that. cURL cannot *interpret* the fetched HTML though, you'll need to use a HTML parser for that. PHP has a DOM extension built in, and there are also third-party classes available.

Comment: after getting the content of the website ,put it in a variable and use string functions and regex expressions to get it.

Comment: What's your larger goal?  I understand your question, but I suspect there may be other ways to accomplish it.

Comment: @SurrealDreams, what do you mean larger goal? I've updated my question to hopefully make people understand what I'm trying to do. I'm just trying to learn mostly...

Comment: I'm wondering what you really want to accomplish - there might be a better way to get this to work.  It's good that you want to learn, but there might be more practical applications or other ways to use the tools to teach you how they work.

Comment: My only accomplishment is to get the text from a div class even though there's two classes, maybe I can somehow call the photo class, and from that same div, get the other class? That's my only accomplishment at the moment. Do you think there is a way to do such a thing? I may be able to somehow use jquery and do `.attr("photo")` but not sure how to obtain the other class within this photo div.

Comment: cURL is server side. You won't be able to use jQuery at all, unless you pass the output to a browser; but that would be ridiculous :) -- Check my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cURL` is only half the solution. Its job is simply to retrieve the content. Once you have that content, then you can do string or structure manipulation. There are some text functions you could use, but it seems like you're looking for something specific among this content, so you may need something more robust.

Therefore, for this HTML content, I'd suggest researching [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/domdocument), as it will structure your content into an XML-like hierarchy, but is more forgiving of the looser nature of HTML markup.

```
$ch = curl_init();
// [Snip cURL setup functions]
$content = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($content); // We use @ here to suppress a bunch of parsing errors that we shouldn't need to care about too much.

$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    if (strpos($div->getAttribute('class'), 'photo') !== false) {
      // Now we know that our current $div is a photo
      $targetValue = explode(' ', $dom->getAttribute('class'));

      // $targetValue will now be an array with each class definition.
      // What is done with this information was not part of the question,
      //   so the rest is an exercise to the poster.
    }
}
```

Comment: @delive - Presumably this would be in the "[Snip cURL setup functions]" block :) The focus was on the parsing of the data.

Comment: I know, but other people not know, you need be clear to post a example :)